# wordpress filter for searching categories with ajax not working

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to implement a filter to show posts by categories, my elaborate code works but the filter result shows it offsite in /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

I would like the filter results to be displayed on the same page without loading another page.

The Form:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <?php
        if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
            echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option>Select category...</option>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
            endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="date" value="ASC" /> Date: Ascending
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="date" value="DESC" selected="selected" /> Date: Descending
    </label>
    <button>Apply filters</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="customfilter">
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script>jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Applying Filters...');          },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filters');                $('#response').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});</script>
```

The Function:

```
<?php 
function my_filters(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => $_POST['date']
    );
  
        if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );
   
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;
  
    die();
}
  
  
add_action('wp_ajax_customfilter', 'my_filters');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customfilter', 'my_filters');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, the issue seems to lie in the HTML form action attribute, where you're posting to admin-ajax.php. Because of this, your page is being redirected to that URL. Instead, you should prevent the form submission from redirecting the page by using JavaScript.

Your JavaScript code should be like:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from redirecting to a new page
        var filter = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', // The AJAX PHP handler
            data: filter.serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                filter.find('button').text('Applying Filters...');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filters');
                $('#response').html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filters');
                $('#response').html('An error occurred');
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

With the above changes, your AJAX request should run on the current page without refreshing or redirecting, and then it should populate the `#response` div with the data returned by your AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you @Ray is working now